# Is there a way to tell if it is the first time in a for loop?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am working on a project, and can't figure out how to make it so something else happens the first iteration of the loop happens so it will print some thing different. Does anybody know how to do this?

This is my code:

```
while True:
    var = input('text here')
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, please share a snip code. Wellcome to SO, please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes, we do. Can you be concrete as to which problem you are solving and what your code is?

Comment: Typically, you want to "extract" the item that would be handled by the first iteration and put that *before* the loop. Then the loop itself has no special case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply check the index in the loop, for example:

```py
for i in range(10):
    if i == 0:
        print("First iteration")
    else:
        print("Other")
```

Comment: I will make it iterate! Thanks for the help! ( :

Answer (score 4):

In the case of a while loop:

```
first_time = True
while True:
    if first_time:
        first_time = False
        # do first time stuff
    # do stuff every time
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the loop index variable is 0.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep track of the place in the loop.

Without enumerate:

```
i = 0
for item in iterable_datatype:
    if i == 0:
        # do something on only first iteration
    else:
        #do something on every other iteration
    # do something on every iteration
    i += 1
```

With enumerate

```
for i, item in enumerate(iterable_datatype):
    if i == 0:
        # do something on only first iteration
    else:
        #do something on every other iteration
    # do something on every iteration
```

Enumerate basically does what the first for loop does for you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something different on the first iteration of a loop, put the different stuff before the loop, and adjust your loop range:

```
print("First 'iteration'")
for i in range(1, 10):
    print("Other")
```